# ngBlur and ngFocus will not work together

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need to make a prepopulated text field that resets to its initial value if the user enters an invalid (empty) string. To achieve this I have the following javascript:

```
  $scope.storeValueFor = function(object) {
    if(object && object.value) {
      $scope.fallback = object.value;
    }
  };

  $scope.updateValueFor = function(holder, object) {
    if(object.value && object.value.length > 0) {
      update(holder, object);
    } else {
      object.value = $scope.fallback;
    }
  };
```

I want storeValueFor() to be called when the field is placed in focus, and updateValueFor() to be called when focus is lost. Here is the relevant part of my HTML:

```
          <input ng-model="object.value"
                 ng-show="!hideInput()"
                 ng-blur="updateValueFor(holder, object)"
                 ng-focus="storeValueFor(object)"
                 ng-minlength="1">
          <span ng-bind-html="formatString(object.value)" ng-hide="hideInput()"></span>
```

Now, my issue is that only the top directive (ng-blur or ng-focus) is actually active. In other words, here updateValueFor() would be called, but not storeValueFor(). If I change it so that ng-focus is on top it will be the other way around.

I have found a working example of this combination [here](http://jsfiddle.net/deathhell/UTn5y/2/), but when I replace my function calls with the inline functions seen here the behaviour persists.

Does anyone have an idea of what could cause this?

Edit: As it turns out this behaviour only manifests on the instance of Chrome I use for development and as such have AngularJs Batarang installed on. Disabling this extension removes the problem. Can someone give me an idea of why this is happening?

Comment: Can corroborate.  Happening for me in Chrome version 41.0.2272.76 as well.  Thanks for the edit to your original post for at least pointing out the underlying problem. Batarang is now disabled.  :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out this behaviour only manifests on the instance of Chrome I use for development and as such have AngularJs Batarang installed on. Disabling this extension removes the problem.